# MS Access combobox in a continuous form changes value for all rows when I change value for one row

Tags: ms-access

I've been trying to solve this issue for the past 2 hours but in vain...
So I hope that you can help me with a solution to this problem..
I have a continuous form that shows many rows at a time, I added a combobox to the form that shows some values to choose from another table, while having the default value shown from the same table. Problem is, as soon as I change the value in one of the comboboxes in the form, all the other comboboxes changes value to the same one as the latter...
How do I prevent that??
Thanks a million in advance

Answer (score 5):

Tony's right.  You can't do what you want with an unbound control.

However, it's not entirely clear what your intent is based on your question.  If changing the combobox should update a field on the current record, then you just need to make it a bound control.  You would do this by setting the combobox's ControlSource property equal to the appropriate field in the underlying table or query.

Comment: It's very common for the first of two cascading combo boxes to be unbound. I would never use a continuous form to edit when I needed that -- instead, I'd use the continuous form/datasheet form as a list, and load the editable data in a subform linked with LinkMaster/LinkChild properties using an expression pointing to the PK of the record selected in the continuous/datasheet form.

Answer (score 4):

I faced similar issue and got it sorted recently. I had created a tabular form and had introduced a combo box in the form, picking up values from a value list. Whenever I used to select a value of this combo box list, the selection used to get reflecting on all the records. To correct this, you should do the following:-

1) Introduce the combo box field in the source table of your form. Instead of clicking on the drop down box in the tool box, click on the Add existing fields link on the ribbon and select the newly added combo box field from the table. This will add a combo box field and a corresponding label in the form area. For a tabular form, you may want to delete the corresponding label and introduce a non-linked label in the form header.

This solved the issue for me. Hope it will be of some value to you.

May be a couple of years late and am pretty sure that it's been long since you figured out this problem,but it's good to leave it in the thread for someone,who may be in need.

Answer (score 2):

Can't be done.  This is one of the limitations of Access continuous forms and unbound controls.

Comment: ...and is one of several reasons why I generally don't use editable continuous/datasheet forms, particularly when there are conditional alterations to controls (such as cascading combo boxes).

Answer (score 0):

Because of this strange behavior I just hide that field.

In the datasheet view:

- Right-Click the field header that matches your combobox
- Select "Hide Fields"

Now the person can see the records and they can use the form. They don't need a field for the combobox.