# Dependent multipick lists

Tags: forms, ms-access, dependencies

I have a question regarding dependent multipick lists. I have subjects Client and organization. Client and Organization can come together in tjnClient^Organization. Within tblOrganization, you are able to select various services that the organization can offer. On the junction table between these subjects, there is a relationship to the same lookup table for services, offering a choice of services used by the client. I am needing a way to limit the choice of services for each client/org pair based on the org's choices on their table.

Here is what I have done:

1. I created a query, qryOrganization_Services. In that query, I have returned the primary keys of the organizations and their services, using an inner join to only collect the organizations which have picked services.

[qryOrganization_Services](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TYsz0.jpg)

2. I have limited this query to have an organization primary key equal to the cboOrganization-RecordIdentifier, which is the combo box where the user selects an organization on the junction form between Client and Organization.
3. The rowsource for the combo box to select services that the client uses has been set up with an inner join between the services lookup table and the query mentioned earlier.

[rowsource](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wlFBw.jpg)

4. I placed a requery macro on the AfterUpdate for the combo box to choose an organization, as well as a requery on the OnCurrent for the form.

The issue is the following. It appears that every single record updates its client services box based on the very first record’s choice of organization. I am not sure what is causing this.

Any thoughts appreciated.

Comment: This is normal behavior for Continuous or Datasheet form because there is only one combobox for Services - programmatically setting its properties affects ALL instances of control - every record will reflect same property setting. This is a known issue and topic of many discussions. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6761416/ms-access-combobox-in-a-continuous-form-changes-value-for-all-rows-when-i-change and https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_access-mso_win10-mso_2016/cascading-combo-in-continuous-form/62a3384c-03a2-4ec7-bd9b-4d8d31dcedcc

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Custom row source for combo box in continuous form in Access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86278/custom-row-source-for-combo-box-in-continuous-form-in-access)

Comment: I will attempt the method in the third link. I'm still looking for a solution to this, but it appears simply attempting to limit my list box based on the combo box given for the organization in the same form is not something that's possible.

Comment: Can limit listbox, just cannot have variable list for each record at same time in Continuous or Datasheet form. Referenced links show method of dealing with this.

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstood the link's solutions. To clarify, I have two tables (one subject (let's say subject B for shorthand) and one junction (Between A and B)) which have a foreign key for a category. Within the junction form, I have a foreign key combo box for subject B. I also have the junction's side of the category listbox. I would like to limit the the listbox based on the value of subject B I pick. Recall that subject B has a corresponding listbox in its own form , with its own values picked. I hope I'm clear.

Comment: Yes, you are describing cascading combox/listbox which does not work nicely on continuous or datasheet form. Referenced links describe a workaround.

Comment: I will look into them further and let you know if it ended up working. Thank you.

Comment: I should have clarified that cascading combobox/listbox doesn't work nice on continuous or datasheet form when alias is involved. That is when combo/list box has primary key as saved value but displays descriptive value. That is when the workaround is needed.

Comment: @June7, do you know if the combo box in question MUST be unbound like your final link suggests? I can't do it this way. It seems that if I create an unbound combo box, I lose the ability to achieve the multi select feature. I am not using a listbox due to this being a long list and I'm wanting to reserve space.

Comment: Sorry to pester @June7. But, there might be a problem with the suggested solution. When I get to the step of having the combo box fill the textbox with the selected options on AfterUpdate, this works for the instance in question. The problem is that when I go choose options from the NEXT record's combo box, it not only updates its own textbox, but every textbox prior. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that you are allowing multi-select combobox. A combobox can only be multi-select if it is bound to a multi-value field. So, what you want is not practical with multi-value and multi-select. I NEVER use multi-value field.